# Конвертировать текстовые данные в объект JS

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте!

Есть следующий текст:

```
connect.host="192.0.0"
connect.user="root"
base.pass="12345"
log = 20
```

Нужно сделать объект вида:

```
 {
   "connect":{
         "host":"192.0.0",
         "user":"root"
         },
   "base":{
        "pass":"12345"
        },
    "log":"20"
}
```

Текст может меняться каждый раз. 
Код который начал писать:

```
    var data = $('#data').text(),
    elements = data.trim().split(" ");

for(i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    var pair = elements[i].split('='),
        properties = pair[0], //[0]'connect.host'//[1] connect.user..
        value = pair[1];    //[0]"192.0.0"//[1] root ....
    createObj(properties, value); 
}

var object = {};

function createObj(properties, value){

  for(i=0;i<properties.length;i++){

  }

}
```

Как правильно сбить это все в один объект?

Comment: а что имеется ввиду под "текст может каждый раз меняться"? приведите пример такого изменённого текста

Comment: @MasterAlex я имею ввиду, что данные будут меняться. Мне нужно сделать программное создание объекта. Т.е. я могу  создать объект из этих данных, например: var obj = {};obj.connect = {host: "192.0.0",user:"root"} , но эти данные заранее могут быть неизвестны.

Comment: @PavelNET: Непонятно, что делать с таким случаем:

    connect=1
    connect.user="root"

В любом случае вам надо разбить property по точке на части, проверить существование каждой из частей, и если ещё нету, добавить пустой объект (`{}`).

Comment: @PavelNET, то есть постоянными будут только connect, base, log, остальное может меняться?

Comment: @MasterAlex в общем, да.

Comment: @VladD, на счет точки вы правы - я так и хотел делать(split('.')). Это будет массив свойств.  На счет "добавить пустой объект" - не понял вас.

Comment:     connect=1
    connect.user="root"

если такой случай допустим, то надо предусмотреть поле вроде _value в котором хранить примитив. т.е. получится что-то такое:

    connect: {
        _value: 1,
        user: 'root'
    }

Comment: @eicto нет,  таких ситуация не  будет.

Comment: @PavelNET, зачем вам это надо? Откуда берется входной текст?

Comment: @PavelNET: Ну, смотрите. Вам нужно добавить `connect.host`. Если свойства `connect` нет, то добавляется пустой объект. Теперь объект `connect` есть, и вы можете добавить в него свойство `host`.

Вам придётся различать между промежуточными свойствами (где вам нужно добавлять пустой объект) и конечными (где вам нужно добавить свойство нужного типа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var content = "...text..".trim().split("\n");

for(var i=0, obj = {}; i < content.length; i++) {
    var split_full = content[i].split("=");
    var s_dotted = split_full[0].split(".");

    for(k=1, json_string = '', json_string_end = ''; k < s_dotted.length; k++) {
        json_string += '{"' +s_dotted[k].trim() + '":';
        json_string_end += "}";
    }

    json_string += split_full[1].trim() + json_string_end;

    obj[s_dotted[0]] = MergeRecursive(JSON.parse(json_string), obj[s_dotted[0]]);
}

function MergeRecursive(obj1, obj2) {
    for (var p in obj2) {
        try {
            obj1[p] =  ( obj2[p].constructor==Object ) ? MergeRecursive(obj1[p], obj2[p]) : obj1[p] = obj2[p];
        } catch(e) {
            obj1[p] = obj2[p];
        }
    }
    return obj1;
}

console.log(obj);
```

А если используем `jQuery`, то функцию `MergeRecursive()` убираем и

```
obj[s_dotted[0]] = MergeRecursive(JSON.parse(json_string), obj[s_dotted[0]]);
```

заменяем на:

```
obj[s_dotted[0]] = $.extend({}, JSON.parse(json_string), obj[s_dotted[0]]);
```